# Youtube Data API - how to get all videos in a playlist rather than just 50?

Tags: javascript, youtube

To start, here is a reference for what I'm asking about: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

In my javascript code I use a playlist request from the data API like this:

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
  playlistId: listId,
  part: 'snippet',
  maxResults: 50
});
```

Does anybody know a way, without going back to the v2 API which is deprecated, to get all videos in a playlist rather than being stuck with the most recent 50? The maxResults parameter ranges from 0-50 and it would be awesome to find a way to get around that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not stucked. In response you should have next page token. Read more about pageToken and you will have your answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I am not able to test what pageToken does at the moment since one of the key google servers necessary for my app to run is experiencing an internal server error. But I'll let you know if it works out. Thanks again!